# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to find dates in a pandas dataframe based on highest column values. And then figure out a way to plot the data of these individual dates..

I can sort the pandas df easily and plot the dates with the code below but Im not sure if a `.to_list()` would be preferred method ...

```
sort_by_kW = master_hrs.filter(regex='diff$',axis=1)

sort_by_kW = sort_by_kW.sort_values((
[
        'kW1diff',
        'kW2diff',
        'kW3diff',
        'kW4diff',
        'kW5diff',
        'kW6diff',
        'kW7diff',
        'kW8diff',
        'kW9diff',
        'kW10diff',
        'kW11diff',
        'kW12diff',
        'kW13diff',
        'kW14diff',
        'kW15diff',
        'kW16diff']
))

sort_by_kW15 = sort_by_kW.index[0:15].to_list()

sort_by_kW15
```

This yields which I am hoping to plot each of these days individually on a copy of the original dataset named `df_copy`:

```
[Period('2013-12-10', 'D'),
 Period('2013-07-17', 'D'),
 Period('2013-12-11', 'D'),
 Period('2013-09-07', 'D'),
 Period('2014-06-07', 'D'),
 Period('2013-11-29', 'D'),
 Period('2013-08-26', 'D'),
 Period('2013-08-27', 'D'),
 Period('2014-01-03', 'D'),
 Period('2013-11-11', 'D'),
 Period('2014-01-11', 'D'),
 Period('2013-11-24', 'D'),
 Period('2013-11-03', 'D'),
 Period('2013-07-07', 'D'),
 Period('2013-12-12', 'D')]
```

This code below obviously doesn't work, but can the `.loc` be used to access each of the 15 days listed above and then plot in a for loop?

```
for idx, days in sort_by_kW15.groupby(sort_by_kW15.index.date):

    sort_by_kW15.loc[days]
    df_copy.plot()
```

This errors out:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'`

Comment: The problem is your `to_list()` call which generates a native `Python` list. A list does not have a `groupby` method attached while a dataframe has.

Comment: Any chance you can post an answer with something better?

Comment: Would an array, tuple, or dictionary be better data structure to use?